# Is there a faster way to search every column of a dataframe for a String than with .apply and str.contains?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization, apply

So basically i have a bunch of dataframes with about 100 columns and 500-3000 rows filled with different String values. Now I want to search the entire Dataframe for lets say the String "Airbag" and delete every row which doesnt contain this String? I was able to do this with the following code:

```
df = df[df.apply(lambda row: row.astype(str).str.contains('Airbag', regex=False).any(), axis=1)]
```

This works exactly like i want to, but it is way too slow. So i tried finding a way to do it with Vectorization or List Comprehension but i wasn't able to do it or find some example code on the internet. So my question is, if it is possible to fasten this process up or not?

Example Dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['Airbag_101', 'Distance_xy', 'Sensor_2'], 'col2': ['String1', 'String2', 'String3'], 'col3': ['Tires', 'Wheel_Airbag', 'Antenna']})
```

Comment: Please provide an example dataframe

Comment: @Hipman8 If your numpy answer gives you the desired output, you should edit your question because it won't be clear for future googlers. Your code tests for the *exact* string `Airbag` (not substring) but your sample `df` doesn't contain a single `Airbag`. Also even if we change `Airbag_102` and `Wheel_Airbag` to just `Airbag`, your code does not "delete every row which doesn't contain this string" (first two rows). If you want to remove rows in which any column contains the exact string `Airbag`, use something like `df.loc[df.eq('Airbag').any(1)]` like in my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start from this dataframe with random strings and numbers in `COLUMN`:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)
strings = np.apply_along_axis(''.join, 1, np.random.choice(list('ABCD'), size=(100, 5)))
junk = list(range(10))
col = list(strings)+junk
np.random.shuffle(col)
df = pd.DataFrame({'COLUMN': col})
```

```
>>> df.head()
  COLUMN
0  BBCAA
1      6
2  ADDDA
3  DCABB
4  ADABC
```

You can simply apply [`pandas.Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html). You need to use [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) to account for the non-string elements:

```
>>> df[df['COLUMN'].str.contains('ABC').fillna(False)]
    COLUMN
4    ADABC
31   BDABC
40   BABCB
88   AABCA
101  ABCBB
```

#### testing all columns:

Here is an alternative using a good old custom function. One could think that it should be slower than `apply`/`transform`, but it is actually faster *when you have a lot of columns* and a decent frequency of the seached term (tested on the example dataframe, a 3x3 with no match, and 3x3000 dataframes with matches and no matches):

```
def has_match(series):
    for s in series:
        if 'Airbag' in s:
            return True
    return False


df[df.apply(has_match, axis=1)]
```

Comment: Yes i know this would work, but i want to search through every column to find a String. I have edited my question and added an example dataframe.

Comment: Well, optimizing algorithms is always tricky. It depends on what your data looks like. Do you expect to have a lot of columns to drop? Within a column what is the expected frequency of the searched term? I added an alternative that should be faster when you have a high frequency of the searched term.

Answer (score 1):

##### Update (exact match)

Since it looks like you actually want an exact match, test with [`eq()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) instead of `str.contains()`. Then use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#different-choices-for-indexing) with `loc`:

```py
df.loc[df.eq('Airbag').any(axis=1)]
```

---

##### Original (substring)

Test for the string with [`applymap()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) and turn it into a row mask using [`any(axis=1)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html):

```py
df[df.applymap(lambda x: 'Airbag' in x).any(axis=1)]

#           col1     col2          col3
# 0   Airbag_101  String1         Tires
# 1  Distance_xy  String2  Wheel_Airbag
```

---

As mozway said, "optimal" depends on the data. These are some timing plots for reference.

- Timings vs number of rows (fixed at 3 columns):

  [image: timings vs row count]
- Timings vs number of columns (fixed at 3,000 rows):

  [image: timings vs col count]

Comment: Thanks for the comparison! NB. the speed of my function is not strictly proportional to the size of the array, it will perform best when the searched string is very common and slowly otherwise. But as the question was ambiguous on the real use case, it is difficult to conclude here…

Comment: ah good point! later i might try some timings vs match proportion/location, just out of curiosity.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I was able to speed it up with the help of numpy arrays, but thanks for the help :D

```
master_index = []
for column in df.columns:
   np_array = df[column].values
   index = np.where(np_array == 'Airbag')
   master_index.append(index)
print(df.iloc[master_index[1][0]])
```

Comment: You don't need to loop to test strict equality. Also, this solution does **not** solve the problem you described but another one ;)